# Android reverse geocoding requires either an Internet connection or a backend data provider

Tags: android, geolocation, google-places-api, android-location, google-geocoding-api

I've just delved into the world of Global Positioning System (GPS) and found the following interesting facts:

1) The Android class `android.location.Geocoder` always returns `null` when getting address via reverse geocoding. The code I used is:

```
Geocoder mGeocoder = new Geocoder(context, locale);
List<Address> addresses = mGeocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
    // do something.
} else {
    // Display a message regarding no address available.
}
```

The reason is stated [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html):

> The Geocoder class requires a backend service that is not included in
>   the core android framework.

So, essentially I would either have to provide offline geolocation data myself for reverse geocoding, or my Android app will have to connect to the Internet and look up geolocation data from Google (via `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=` for example). Or use alternative geolocation providers like [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), etc.

2) Android apps like Google Maps requires an Internet connection; while offline provider like TomTom bundled offline geolocation data together with their app so an Internet connection is not needed.

Beside the stated facts above, is there another alternative for retrieving geolocation address without using offline reverse geographic data or using an Internet connection?

If you have some experience with geocoding and reverse geocoding in Android, then please post your thoughts.

Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the methods you've stated in your post, I don't know of any other method for reverse geocoding.

Comment: For OSM based geocoding you can try the Telenav SDK as they come with offline geocoding and reverse geocoding: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec019

Answer (score 0):

There is at least one way for each.

For reverse-geocoding, you let the user mark the geolocation of the address himself using gps.

For geocoding, you let the user hunt down a set of coordinates and then you have him read the street name and the address he finds himself at.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer, but my requirement is different to what you have suggested. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are few offline libraries available to reverse Geocode offilne. Suggest you to go through these libraries.Personally i have not used these libraries.Let me know if you still face any problems.

https://developers.arcgis.com/android/

Sample code for link:

[https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-android/tree/master/OfflineRoutingAndGeocoding)